# How to bookmark a custom URL in Chrome mobile browser?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I have an entry URL into an ***app1*** like

```
https://www.example.com/go/app1
```

which actually goes through a few redirects including SSO login and then finishes on something like

```
https://www.example.com/app1/home/session-f24a-3c29-843924fd001eea-1234
```

I need to bookmark the former URL (`.../go/app1`) because the latter cannot be directly accessed when the session expires. How can I bookmark that URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can add a different bookmark and then edit it to what you need.

1. Open Chrome.
2. Open your address `https://www.example.com/go/app1` and wait until the final page (with different URL) is read. (Or use any other URL but the previous one may already gives more accurate page title useful for the bookmark.)
3. Click the menu, then click ☆ (star) to bookmark current page.
4. On the menu, click **Bookmarks**.
5. Find the bookmark from step **3**.
6. Click the 3-dot on the right, select **Edit**, then change the URL to your custom URL `https://www.example.com/go/app1`.